# RStudio View() extremely slow when viewing nested dataframes

Tags: r

I'm running the latest version of R (4.3.2) as well as RStudio and it takes several minutes to open even a small nested data frame. By small I mean hundreds of rows of data per nested data frame and only a couple of nested data frames.

Did something happen with the latest update? Anyone else having this issue?
Even opening the "arrow" inside the environment in RStudio takes forever.

Comment: I have noticed the same issue. I had to turn off the autocompletion data preview setting in RStudio to prevent RStudio from becoming unresponsive whenever I'd write the object name or hover over it.

Comment: Be sure to report this issue so Posit can fix it

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding @Till's answer as the answer to my question. Turning off `Show data preview in autocompletion help popup` from the Code -> Completion menu under global options seems to solve this very annoying issue!

Comment: You should let @Till answer so he can be given some rep points

Comment: Sure, I'll remove my answer if he wants to.